# solving equations by the method of substitution

Tags: linear-algebra

$\dfrac{a}{x}+\dfrac{b}{y}=\dfrac{a}{2}+\dfrac{b}{3},$

$x+1=y$

We have to solve for $x$ and $y$.I have tried to solve for them by finding value of $x$ or $y$ from the second equation and place them in the second.It is obvious that the answers would be $2$ and $3,$but we need something else. I tried to find the relation between $a$ and $b$ and them place them again in the first equation along with the value of $x$ or $y$ ,  but it yields something bizarre. So how do we solve it? A tiny hint will be appreciated.

Comment: I've edited your question to make it more readable. Please correct me if this is not the question you intended.

Comment: In your original question, LaTeX would have been very useful. If LaTeX is not used, then a generous use of parentheses is necessary.

Comment: Can you put '$' around your math? It will make it much easier to read.

Comment: @Andre I did a disastrous job when typing it the first time.Hope it is at least understandable this time.

Comment: @rahul: You did a good job, given the lack of parentheses, commas, and the unfortunate spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** (1) Multiply each side of the first equation by $(2)(3)(x)(y)$; (2) Then replace $y$ by $x+1$; (3) Rearrange, you get a quadratic equation in $x$.

You could solve the resulting equation using the Quadratic Formula. Actually, the quadratic factors nicely.

Alternately, you spotted one of the roots. If you know one root of a quadratic, then by glancing at the coefficients you can find the other. This is because in the quadratic equation $px^2+qx+r=0$, the product of the roots is $r/p$ and the sum of the roots is $-q/p$. You will find the product criterion more pleasant. If you use it you don't even need to calculate the messisest coefficient of the quadratic, the coefficient of $x$.

Comment: Thanks,but why was it not working when I tried to find the relation between a and b amd place them.in the equation,

Comment: There is no relationship between $a$ and $b$, they are independent parameters. By the way, for a complete solution you will have to deal with the degenerate case $\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{3}=0$, but that's easy. You asked for a hint, and I gave a very detailed one. But if you have trouble completing, please leave a message and I can add a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{a}{x}+\dfrac{b}{y}=\dfrac{a}{2}+\dfrac{b}{3}$...........$(1)$

$x+1=y$............$(2)$

From (2),$x=y-1$. Substituting it into $(1)$,

$\dfrac{a}{y-1}+\dfrac{b}{y}=\dfrac{a}{2}+\dfrac{b}{3}$

$\implies \dfrac{a}{y-1}-\dfrac{a}{2}=\dfrac{b}{3}-\dfrac{b}{y}$

$\implies \dfrac{2a-ay+a}{2(y-1)}=\dfrac{b(y-3)}{3y}$

$\implies \dfrac{3a-ay}{2(y-1)}=\dfrac{b(y-3)}{3y}$

$\implies \dfrac{a(3-y)}{2(y-1)}=\dfrac{b(y-3)}{3y}$

$\implies \dfrac{a(3-y)}{2(y-1)}=-\dfrac{b(3-y)}{3y}$  [Multiplying the fraction on the right side by $\dfrac{-1}{-1}$]

$\implies \dfrac{a(3-y)}{2(y-1)}+=0$

$\implies (3-y)[\dfrac{a}{2(y-1)}+\dfrac{b}{3y}]=0$

Since the product of two numbers is 0,at least one of them must be 0.........

No quadratic formula needed!